# Couldn't find org.gradle.api dependency

Tags: java, gradle

I try to use DefaultTask and can't add the `org.gradle.api.*` dependency.

I added dependency from the https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gradle/api/1.0:

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gradle/api
    implementation group: 'org.gradle', name: 'api', version: '1.0'
```

but the project still does not "see" org.gradle... library:

[image]

`gradle build` execution result:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.gradle:api:1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gradle/api/1.0/api-1.0.pom
```

Full build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

test{
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-email', version: '1.5'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gradle/api
    implementation group: 'org.gradle', name: 'api', version: '1.0'
}
```

**Why has the dependency doesn't been found?**

Comment: Could you provide your full `build.gradle` code and project layout?

Answer (score 2):

From the official doc https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.1/userguide/custom_tasks.html#sec:custom_tasks_standalone_project, its `build.gradle` is very simple.

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    // id 'java' <----- use this if written in Java
}

dependencies {
    implementation gradleApi()
}
```

You don't have to specify `org.gradle:api` in `dependencies{}` nor `mavenCentral()` in `repositories{}`. The one you found in https://mvnrepository.com is a very old version. I guess they host the JARs themselves.